# How to implement otp functionality in android application through email

Tags: android, one-time-password

I want to implement OTP functionality in my android application. In this application, after entering the email id it check whether user is exist or not. If user email id does not exist user will receive one time password key(OTP). After receiving OTP, user will be able to sign in to application. What I need to do to achieve this on my application?

Comment: use Firebase Authentication. check [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth).

Comment: @AvinashKarn Are you using web services/API?

Comment: Yes I am using API ..Please help me Shivam

Comment: @ShivamKumar Yes I am using API...Please help me

Comment: First you will send email id to server using API then you will check email id exists or not in your database. If Email id exists in database then you will return a response of already exists or whatever you want. If not exist then you will sent an OTP of email id and API returns not exists and OTP send then you will open OTP screen. When user fill OTP then you will send OTP to server for checking in database on same email id OTP is correct or not. If OTP correct then you will return validate OTP, If OTP does not match then you will return Invalid OTP and show dialog to user please enter valid

Comment: @ShivamKumar there is no need of SMTP to send otp

Comment: @AvinashKarn Then which service is used to send OTP on email id

Comment: @AvinashKarn are you useing firebase authentication

Answer (score 0):

Thre are many ways to this, But we suggest firebase authentication which will give you the full flow of email verification using OTP also provide some other authentication technique if you want following is the official URL which helps you.
[Firebase Auth System](https://firebase.google.com/products/auth/)

Another way you can your custom mechanism.
Custom mechanism steps:
Put static email&Password in the code after inputting email send OTP to inputted mail and store OTP in your DB with email when he tries to verify compare it. Also, maintain some time expiration or something.

Hope this help you!

Comment: Bro through firebase email link authentication is there..How to do this using otp

Comment: I have webservice API

Comment: Then follow second step.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**Add java Class**

```
//This method would confirm the otp
private void confirmOtp() throws JSONException {
    //Creating a LayoutInflater object for the dialog box
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    //Creating a view to get the dialog box
    View confirmDialog = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog_confirm, null);

    //Initizliaing confirm button fo dialog box and edittext of dialog box
    buttonConfirm = (AppCompatButton) confirmDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonConfirm);
    editTextConfirmOtp = (EditText) confirmDialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextOtp);

    //Creating an alertdialog builder
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    //Adding our dialog box to the view of alert dialog
    alert.setView(confirmDialog);

    //Creating an alert dialog
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();

    //Displaying the alert dialog
    alertDialog.show();

    //On the click of the confirm button from alert dialog
    buttonConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Hiding the alert dialog
            alertDialog.dismiss();

            //Displaying a progressbar
            final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Authenticating", "Please wait while we check the entered code", false,false);

            //Getting the user entered otp from edittext
            final String otp = editTextConfirmOtp.getText().toString().trim();

            //Creating an string request
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.CONFIRM_URL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            //if the server response is success
                            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                                //dismissing the progressbar
                                loading.dismiss();

                                //Starting a new activity
                                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Success.class));
                            }else{
                                //Displaying a toast if the otp entered is wrong
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Wrong OTP Please Try Again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                try {
                                    //Asking user to enter otp again
                                    confirmOtp();
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            alertDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    //Adding the parameters otp and username
                    params.put(Config.KEY_OTP, otp);
                    params.put(Config.KEY_USERNAME, username);
                    return params;
                }
            };

            //Adding the request to the queue
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
    });
}
```

**Add another API class**

```
public class Config {
//URLs to register.php and confirm.php file
public static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://simplifiedcoding.16mb.com/AndroidOTP/register.php";
public static final String CONFIRM_URL = "http://simplifiedcoding.16mb.com/AndroidOTP/confirm.php";

//Keys to send username, password, phone and otp
public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
public static final String KEY_OTP = "otp";

//JSON Tag from response from server
public static final String TAG_RESPONSE= "ErrorMessage";
}
```

Comment: bro this for phone Authentication but not email

Comment: Avinash Karn both are same functionality  your backend team handle this

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by step by step.

1. Send email id entered by the user in Application.
2. In API, fetch it and perform Logic to generate OTP code randomly (You can use the function which easily available from Google to generate random code).
3. Add a field namely **"otp_code"** in user's table and update or insert that randomly generated code in the database.
4. Now, implement logic to send an email from API. The email contains all necessary messages and OTP code.
5. After email sent successfully, send a response to the user with that OTP and perform code matching at Android side.